# Using 'this' in a JavaScript Closure

Tags: javascript

I am building an app in JavaScript. I am trying to get my head around how to use `this` in a JavaScript closure. Currently, I have the following code:

```
var ExternalResource = require('ExternalResource');
function MyObject() {
}

MyObject.prototype.state = "Closed";
MyObject.prototype.execute = function(options, callback) {
  if (!options) {
    if (callback) {
      callback(-1);
    }
    return;
  }

  try {
    this.state = 'Connecting';
    var client = new ExternalResource.Client();
    client.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        this.state = 'Failed';
        if (callback) {
          callback(-1, err);
        }
      } else {
        this.state = 'Good';
        if (callback) {
          callback(1);
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (ex) {
    if (callback) {
      callback(-1, ex);
    }
  }
};
```

I am currently executing `execute` by a Jasmine test.

```
it(' - Connect to a local instance', function(done) {
  var myObject = new MyObject();
  myObject.execute({}, function() {
    expect(myObject.state).toBe('Good');
  });
});
```

When this test gets executed, I see the following error:

```
Expected 'Connecting' to be 'Good'.
```

I am sure it has something to do with using `this.state` in the `connect` callback. Yet, I'm not certain.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a `_self` reference into the outer scope so you can properly use it in the inner scope

```
...
var _self = this;
client.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    _self.state = 'Failed';
    if (callback) {
      callback(-1, err);
    }
  } else {
    _self.state = 'Good';
    if (callback) {
      callback(1);
    }
  }
  ...
```